# How to check if instance of `R6` class is present in a vector of class instances

Tags: r, oop, r6

I am looking for a way to check if a given instance of `R6` class is present in a vector of `R6` class instances.

```r
library(R6)

# define a class
Person <- R6Class("Person", list(
  name = NULL,
  initialize = function(name) self$name <- name
))

# create two instances of a class
Jack <- Person$new(name = "Jack")
Jill <- Person$new(name = "Jill")
```

I naively used `%in%` to check this, and it seems to have worked:

```r
# yes
c(Jack) %in% c(Jack, Jill)
#> [1] TRUE
```

But it actually returns `TRUE` no matter the instance:

```r
# also yes
c(Jack) %in% c(Jill)
#> [1] TRUE
```

So I had two questions:

1. What is `%in%` actually matching that it always returns `TRUE`?
2. How can I correctly check if an instance of `R6` class is present in a vector of class instances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R6 objects are environments, `c(Jack)` is a list containing an environment and `%in%` acts like this on lists of environments.

```
e1 <- new.env()
e2 <- new.env()
list(e1) %in% list(e2)
## [1] TRUE
```

Try `identical`

```
sapply(c(Jack , Jill), identical, Jack)
## [1]  TRUE FALSE
```

R6 objects have `"R6"` in their class vector so

```
sapply(c(Jack, Jill, sin, 37), inherits, "R6")
## [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```